# Lambda expression java 8 map method

Tags: lambda, java-8

The syntax of map method in java 8 is :

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

but i can use a lambda expression :

```
personList.stream().filter(p -> p.getPersonType().equals("student"))
            .map(p -> new Student(p.getId(), p.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How does the argument in map method equates to a Function datatype.Please help me understand this .

Thanks

Comment: You can write like this `Function<Person,Person> function = p -> new Student(p.getId(), p.getName())`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper` of the `map` method basically represents any function taking one parameter and returning a value so in this specific case the lambda `p -> new Student(p.getId(), p.getName())` *is a* function taking a `Person` p and returning a `Student` hence fits into that perfectly.

To look at it another way, the lambda is equivalent to:

```
.map(new Function<Person, Student>() {
     @Override
      public Student apply(Person p) {
            return new Student(p.getId(), p.getName());
      }
})
```

Comment: while i got stuck here i found this explaination https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood quite helpfull too.

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this `Function<Person,Student> function = p -> new Student(p.getId(), p.getName())`

so as you see it is represent a function.

```
personList.stream().filter(p -> p.getPersonType().equals("student"))
        .map(function::apply) // p -> function.apply(p)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your `Stream<Person>` (assuming `personList` is a `List<Person>`), the lambda expression `p -> new Student(p.getId(), p.getName())` implements a functional interface that accepts a `Person` instance (an element of your `Stream`) and returns a `Student` instance.

Hence it matches the `Function<Person,Student>` functional interface, which is the interface required by the `map()` method.

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, the following lambda expression:

```
p -> new Student(p.getId(), p.getName())
```

will be represented by the class that implements `Function<T, R>` interface.

An instance of this functional interface can be passed as a parameter to `Stream.map(...)` method:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

In order to get a better understanding of how this works, one could replace a lambda with a good old anonymous class that implements the corresponding interface.

`.map(p -> new Student(p.getId(), p.getName()))` is equivalent to:

```
.map(new Function<Person, Student>() {
    @Override
    public Student apply(Person p) {
        return new Student(p.getId(), p.getName());
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Ousmane D. but instead of this:

```java
.map(new Function<Person, Student>() {
     @Override
      public Student apply(Person p) {
            return new Student(p.getId(), p.getName());
      }
})
```

Try this:

```java
Function<Person, Student> f = p -> new Student(p.getId(), p.getName());
```

and use it inside your stream with `.map(f)`.